# What date format does excel return?

Tags: c#, excel, datetime, date-format

I'm making a database that will be global and I'm reading the date from an excel file.

I used the local machine's culture when parsing DateTime and was expecting them to match.

```
d = DateTime.Parse(date, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Shouldn't the date from excel have the `CurrentCulture` format?

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" 
                + src +
                ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"");

            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [data$]", con);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
            rows = dt.Rows.Count;
            columns = dt.Columns.Count;

string date = dt.Rows[start].ItemArray[column].ToString();
```

Comment: What are you parsing? Excel dates are simple numbers. Add more info :)

Comment: I'm reading the data form a DataTable as strings and I'm getting something like this 16/03/2014  00:00:00, it works with InvariantCulture but I don't know if it will work in Paris ass well

Comment: How did it get into that DataTable as a string? How are you reading the data from the Excel? How are you reading the values from the DataTable afterwards?

Comment: I added all you need to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) parse your string successfully if the string format fits one of standard date time patterm of your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can find all standart date time patterns in your `CurrentCulture` like;

```
var array = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns();
foreach (var item in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

If both your `CurrentCulture` and Paris's culture (I assume they use `fr-FR` culture) have the same standart format that will match your string format, your parsing will be successful.

Comment: so if I use InvariantCulture it will always parse as long as it is valid format and if I use CurrentCulture it must match some specific formats only?

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu No. If you use `InvariantCulture`, your string format should match one of the pattern that `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns()` method returns. If you use `CurrentCulture`, your string format should match one of the pattern that `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns()` method returns. All cultures have their own standard date and time format patterns. They can have same patterns and different patterns as well each other.

Comment: can I be sure I get a match with InstalledUICulture? This program will be deployed globally (even China) so I need to be able to parse whatever format is present on that machine. Also once I parse it to date time it's the same no matter the culture used right?

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu That's totally depends on your `InstalledUICulture` (`GetSystemDefaultUILanguage` in the Windows API as said it's documentation.).  There is no such a thing like "_Parse my string whatever format is_". If you want to parse custom date and time format, you can use `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` methods.

Comment: but since I'm reading it form excel (where the value is actually an int) it can only give me an installed format right?

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu Then I need to ask, why do you keep your datetimes as an `int`? Which format you inserted in excel, you get the same format (if you don't made any formatting change).

Comment: I don't make the excel file, I just looked at the value inside the cell witch is a number and formated as date so the output changes if I change the regional settings

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, that's exactly what I thought - Excel is giving you a proper date, then *you* convert it to string and try to do the opposite again. Instead, you want to get the date straight from the data table:

```
DateTime date = (DateTime)dt.Rows[start][column];
```

Note that for `null` values, the type will not be `DateTime`, but rather `DBNull`, so you'd want to check for that first:

```
DateTime? date = dt.Rows[start][column] is DBNull 
                 ? default(DateTime?) 
                 : (DateTime)dt.Rows[start][column];
```

Comment: Specified cast is not valid. It's not stored as a date in the DataTable because when I look inside it's a string there (object {string})

Comment: Excel only returns it as a DateTime if the cell was set as Date in Excel. If it is set to General, Excel likes to guess what the type is, and that's generally not what you want (it could start returning strings and datetimes randomly).

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu Yeah, as Flater said, it has to be a date in Excel. The thing is, if it isn't a date in Excel, you have no idea what the string means - it doesn't matter where your code is running, it's all about how the guy who wrote it wrote it (not about *your* Excel's locale). Which may be *his* locale, or even some other format, whatever he wants. Always use the correct data format - otherwise you're just hurting everyone trying to work with that data :)

Comment: I don't make the excel file, I just looked at the value inside the cell witch is a number and formated as date so the output in excel changes if I change the regional settings

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu Weird, that probably means that the OleDb provider can't interpret the file properly, most likely because it's not a proper table layout. If that's so, you're more or less out of luck using OLE DB - if you can't read the file another way, guessing is probably the only option. But it's a problem. How do you distinguish between `mm/dd/yyyy` and `dd/mm/yyyy`? Or `mm/dd/yy` and `yy/mm/dd`?